How to Catch Jetton Transfers and Identify the Token in a Tact Smart Contract?
I am working on a Tact smart contract for TON (The Open Network) and need to handle Jetton transfers. Specifically, I would like to know how to:
Catch Jetton transfers within my Tact smart contract.
Identify which Jetton (token) was transferred during this process.

I've looked through the Tact documentation but haven’t found clear instructions on how to implement this in the contract. How can I listen for the transfer and then identify the Jetton/token type?
Any guidance, example code, or documentation reference would be helpful!
Thanks in advance.

Hi, were you able to find the answer to this question?

Token transfer in TON contracts occurs as follows:

Someone sends message to its own jetton wallet contract for jetton transfer to you:

message(0x0f8a7ea5) JettonTransfer {
    query_id: Int as uint64;
    amount: Int as coins;
    destination: Address;
    response_destination: Address;
    custom_payload: Cell?;
    forward_ton_amount: Int as coins;
    forward_payload: Slice as remaining;
}

2.jetton wallet (if everything is ok) notifies your jetton wallet that it's transfered tokens to you:
message(0x178d4519) JettonTransferInternal {
    query_id: Int as uint64;
    amount: Int as coins;
    from: Address;
    response_destination: Address;
    forward_ton_amount: Int as coins;
    forward_payload: Slice as remaining;
}


IF someone in 1 stage above set transfer parameter forward_ton_amount to not 0, so your jetton wallet sends you notification:

message(0x7362d09c) JettonTransferNotification {
    query_id: Int as uint64;
    amount: Int as coins;
    sender: Address;
    forward_payload: Slice as remaining;
}

In that stage you need to handle this message in your Tact code. That's how you catch jetton transfer
What about identifying jetton. Every jetton has it's jetton wallet contract for each owner. So you need to save jetton wallet addresses of your jetton wallet contracts and verify from which address you received JettonTransferNotification
More details in TON Docs: https://docs.ton.org/develop/dapps/asset-processing/jettons#jetton-on-chain-processing
